# Rails nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nested, nested-forms

In rails how would i build a nested form, similar to the type of form that can be built with the nested_form gem. But instead of nesting a model, i need to nest an attribute of the model which is stored as an array within the model. (it is a text array which is serialized into an array

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think what you want is to define a virtual attribute on the model. Then you can treat it like any other attribute.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes

http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes

also, this post has some good examples:
[Rails: Virtual attributes and form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022974/rails-virtual-attributes-and-form-values)